# Error while installing node and watchman using Homebrew

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew, zsh

[Screenshot of error message from my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYDAG.jpg)

I am trying to set up react native environment for apps dev. I downloaded homebrew successfully, but I cant install watchman or node using the following commands:

```
brew install node
brew install watchman
```

Comment: Hi! As you can see you get a permission error when running the commands. Can you try to run the suggested command ```sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Homebrew``` and report the result?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a potential permissions issue with your Homebrew directory. Have you tried running the recommended commands to try and fix your issue?

```
$ Error: /ur/local/Homebrew is not writable. You should change the ownership and permissions of /us/local/Homebrew back to your user account:
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Homebrew
```

Comment: Also, could you run `brew doctor` to see if it detects any other issues?